# Why does this work once and never work again even if I refresh na page using chrome browser?

Tags: javascript

I was using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox) page as test to check if the code works, and when I hit enter the code does work by checking all checkboxes and making all labels bold but when I refresh the page and try the same thing again it doesn't work anymore.

```
(function() {
    var aa = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var bb = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
    for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++){
        if (aa[i].type == 'checkbox')
            aa[i].checked = true;
            bb[i].textContent.bold();
    }
    
 })()
```

I tried using `console.log(bb[i].textContent.bold()` to check if the code detects the labels and it did the first time. The console says `VM131:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')`. I was expecting that the labels are also turned to bold after checking all the checkboxes

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take a look at the instructions for creating a [mre]. "_Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included in the question itself: \[...\] Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541) to include runnable HTML, JavaScript, or CSS._"

Comment: I'd also suggest you take a look at [ask], which has some good tips on how to write a descriptive title.